# Unjustified treatment from new manager

Tags: human-resources, manager, complaint

I'm working for a big tech company (>100,000 employees).

When I started, I had a different manager than I do today, and I received positive feedback across the board, even when I specifically requested negative feedback.

A few months ago, my manager moved to another team and a colleague was promoted and became my current manager.

It's been difficult to tell exactly when things started to go down-hill, but a few months back I requested a conversation with him to bring up an issue: He has been pushing back on the ideas of myself and a colleague on a shared project and after consulting with my previous manager, he recommended that I'll talk to him and guided me on how to do so.

The conversation did not go well with my manager reacting angrily and impatiently.

Ever since that conversation, my manager has been giving me bad performance reviews, criticizing me in public (for example, posting on the issue management system that I'm slow to respond/fix), and on one occasion, scolding me for bringing up a privacy issue with one of the company's lawyers without letting him know in advance, stating that they had to do "damage control" for my actions - I later spoke to the privacy manager and he reassured me that there was no damage and I did the right thing, leaving me wondering if and why my current manager was lying about that.

To summarize, when I started I was doing very well, on trajectory for a promotion, and now I'm on a trajectory to being fired.

I'm not sure what I should do about it, my options as I see them are:

- Trying to change teams, which is currently very hard as there is a company wide hiring freeze
- Speaking to the skip-level manager - which might back-fire as I'm not sure where he stands on the topic
- Filing an anonymous complaint to HR

I'm worried that it might come out as a petty employee who gets a bad performance review and gets back at his manager instead of trying to improve.

It's worth noting that on paper I appear to have low performance for this quarter as not all my set goals have been met, but when looking at the details, there's plenty contribution outside of the goals set, and there are justified reasons for the slow progress. But my manager sees all that as excuses.

What should I do moving forward? Could there be another option that I'm not seeing?

Comment: It's quite hard to tell whether your boss' complaints are justified or not; for instance when you spoke to the lawyer, did it reflect badly on your team and him? If so, maybe being diplomatic and telling him first would have been better. For another example, why aren't you meeting your set targets and why you contributing other stuff instead?

Comment: How long (approximately) have you been at your current company?  I think that affects your options because if it's a relatively short period of time (say less than a year) you don't necessarily have the long track record to go to your manager's manager and say that you are being treated unfairly.

Comment: And a 4th option? Move to another company??

Comment: My finger is hovering over the Close button - I think though there is a good question somewhere in here. First comments: Do you have proof in writing - specifically around the Privacy claim? If I asked you right now to provide proof that the targets you haven't met are all due to external factors, could you do so? Assume you have that and you raise a grievance against your Manager - what would the Manager respond with? They've got good grounds to say that you should have given them a heads-up on the privacy issue and that you haven't raised the roadblocks with them. Part 1

Comment: Part 2: You need more info from your Manager about what their issue is. It could be a clash of working styles, it could be someone getting used to Management (I'm a terrible Manager but a great Engineer), It could be that your new manager is nervous about 'proving themselves' and is picking up on the small details that they think make them look bad. I don't think either you or us have enough info to provide an answer yet as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

> Could there be another option that I'm not seeing?

You can always search for another job. Often that is the best recourse when there are issues with the hierarchy because it's hard to win battles against them particularly on the information you have given us.

It's also best done sooner than later if the situation is deteriorating.